# How to add price shown on multicurrency

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I want to show the price in my home page, but currently is only showing the type of currency and not the amount. The code looks:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    var lan = $('html')[0].lang
    if(lan == "es-ES"){
        $("div.price-wrapper span:first-child").addClass('mycurrency')
        $(".woocommerce-Price-amount, .woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol").removeClass('mycurrency')
        $(".mycurrency").html('COP')
    }
});
```

here is my home page: https://claudiasanchez.design/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPCpr.png)

I have woomcomerce multilingual plugins

Comment: What happens if you just remove this : $(".mycurrency").html('COP') ?

Comment: oh thank you so much!!!!  It worked on the Spanish page!!!  but now on the english page I don't have the money on USD. How can I change that part?

Comment: On this page its in USD : https://claudiasanchez.design/en/new-arrivals/ ?

Comment: Hi thanks! I was able to fix it! Thanks everyone